# Function using ASReml package in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm using the shareware package `ASReml` within a shiny app. In order to create a model, I need to use the `asreml()` function. I first create the data named `data1`.

If I use the `asreml` function, It works fine :
`model<-asreml(fixed=TRAIT~TEMOIN,random=~PANEL,data=data1,na.method.X="include",na.method.Y="include")`
and `model` is created

The problem is that I want to create a lot of different models in order to choose the best one. The easiest way to do that for me is to create a function that return a list of models. For exemple, I did this :
`Model.list.creator=function(data.sle){
model<-asreml(fixed=TRAIT~TEMOIN,random=~PANEL,data=data.sle,na.method.X="include",na.method.Y="include")
models=list(model)
return(models)
}`

If I use the function in the R console with `Results=Model.list.creator(data.sle=data1)`, I get the model using `Results[[1]]`.
If I use the function within my shiny app, it returns me the error : `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'data.sle' not found` ... just after having diplayed the result of the function!!

NB : the calcul of mod is made in an `observe` loop.

Thanks in advance for any help on this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on the VSNi forum - http://www.vsni.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1081
Assigning formulas to the global environnment make them available even the asreml function is called within a function from a shiny app.

Answer (score 0):

help(observe) "...An observer is like a reactive expression in that it can read reactive values and call reactive expressions, and will automatically re-execute when those dependencies change. But unlike reactive expressions, it doesn't yield a result and can't be used as an input to other reactive expressions..."
Try with reactive instead.